# Return Value to Different Line with Possible Duplicate Information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

In Google Sheets, I need to extract values of D in specific rows and insert them into column I where appropriate.

See link below. Here is an explanation of what I have so far in the spreadsheet:

1. Raw data that I need to modify is in columns A:D.
2. I have an ArrayFormula in E2 that pulls rows from A:D where C is not blank.
3. Where C is blank, I need D to be inserted into I where E:F match A:C. <---This is what I can't figure out.

I'm not married to the formula in E2 if there is a more-efficient way to grab all of the information in one shot. Here's a sample of the data, and what I have so far.

I highlighted groups to show that there are sometimes duplicates or triplicates of the Zone. The value of D should go in I in line with the first iteration of the matching Route/Zone.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xIum-fNKfdS4XWtpaHHJpluTUA3kUEDDMzStQsSxyi4/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the first 50 rows of what I have so far expressed as a CSV. Rows A:D are raw data and rows E:H are from this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(SORT(ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C<>"",A2:D,IFERROR({A2:B,D1:D},""))),1,TRUE))`

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Route** | **Zone** | **Tote** | **Packages** | **Route** | **Zone** | **Tote** | **In Tote** | **NOT in Tote** |
| 102 | J-18.1B | Green 038 | 20 | 102 | J-18.1B | Green 038 | 20 |  |
| 102 | J-18.1B |  | 1 | 102 | J-18.4A | Orange 941 | 14 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4A | Orange 941 | 14 | 102 | J-18.4A | Green 362 | 14 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4A | Green 362 | 14 | 102 | J-18.3A | Black 906 | 13 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4A |  | 1 | 102 | J-18.4C | Navy 891 | 27 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3A | Black 906 | 13 | 102 | J-18.1D | Orange 288 | 16 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3A |  | 1 | 102 | J-18.2D | Navy 952 | 19 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4C | Navy 891 | 27 | 102 | J-18.3D | Black 909 | 14 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4C |  | 1 | 102 | J-18.2B | Green 577 | 31 |  |
| 102 | J-18.1D | Orange 288 | 16 | 102 | J-18.3B | Navy 528 | 17 |  |
| 102 | J-18.1D |  | 1 | 102 | J-18.4B | Yellow 405 | 12 |  |
| 102 | J-18.2D | Navy 952 | 19 | 102 | J-18.4B | Orange 920 | 12 |  |
| 102 | J-18.2D |  | 1 | 102 | J-18.1C | Green 272 | 19 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3D | Black 909 | 14 | 102 | J-18.2C | Orange 425 | 18 |  |
| 102 | J-18.2B | Green 577 | 31 | 102 | J-18.3C | Black 978 | 9 |  |
| 102 | J-18.2B |  | 3 | 103 | H-18.2A | Green 315 | 25 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3B | Navy 528 | 17 | 103 | H-18.3A | Orange 109 | 4 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3B |  | 3 | 103 | H-18.4A | Green 382 | 12 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4B | Yellow 405 | 12 | 103 | H-18.1B | Navy 662 | 10 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4B | Orange 920 | 12 | 103 | H-18.4B | Black 551 | 17 |  |
| 102 | J-18.4B |  | 4 | 103 | H-18.3B | Orange 334 | 28 |  |
| 102 | J-18.1C | Green 272 | 19 | 103 | H-18.2B | Green 456 | 25 |  |
| 102 | J-18.1C |  | 2 | 103 | J-18.4D | Black 741 | 14 |  |
| 102 | J-18.2C | Orange 425 | 18 | 103 | J-18.1E | Yellow 536 | 18 |  |
| 102 | J-18.2C |  | 1 | 103 | J-18.2E | Navy 771 | 17 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3C | Black 978 | 9 | 103 | J-18.3E | Yellow 838 | 23 |  |
| 102 | J-18.3C |  | 1 | 103 | J-18.4E | Orange 970 | 19 |  |
| 103 | H-18.2A | Green 315 | 25 | 103 | J-18.3G | Navy 298 | 15 |  |
| 103 | H-18.2A |  | 2 | 103 | J-18.4G | Black 688 | 19 |  |
| 103 | H-18.3A | Orange 109 | 4 | 103 | H-18.1A | Navy 170 | 13 |  |
| 103 | H-18.3A |  | 1 | 103 | J-18.2G | Orange 681 | 15 |  |
| 103 | H-18.4A | Green 382 | 12 | 103 | J-18.1G | Yellow 508 | 32 |  |
| 103 | H-18.4A |  | 1 | 104 | H-18.2C | Yellow 207 | 17 |  |
| 103 | H-18.1B | Navy 662 | 10 | 104 | H-18.3C | Navy 073 | 16 |  |
| 103 | H-18.1B |  | 1 | 104 | H-18.1C | Yellow 572 | 12 |  |
| 103 | H-18.4B | Black 551 | 17 | 104 | H-18.4C | Yellow 424 | 12 |  |
| 103 | H-18.3B | Orange 334 | 28 | 104 | H-18.1D | Green 087 | 17 |  |
| 103 | H-18.3B |  | 1 | 104 | H-18.2D | Orange 803 | 18 |  |
| 103 | H-18.2B | Green 456 | 25 | 104 | H-18.3D | Black 859 | 23 |  |
| 103 | H-18.2B |  | 1 | 104 | H-18.4D | Navy 525 | 30 |  |
| 103 | J-18.4D | Black 741 | 14 | 104 | H-18.1E | Yellow 227 | 22 |  |
| 103 | J-18.4D |  | 1 | 104 | H-18.2E | Black 021 | 22 |  |
| 103 | J-18.1E | Yellow 536 | 18 | 104 | H-18.3E | Navy 754 | 17 |  |
| 103 | J-18.1E |  | 4 | 104 | H-18.4E | Orange 925 | 15 |  |
| 103 | J-18.2E | Navy 771 | 17 | 104 | H-18.1G | Black 575 | 8 |  |
| 103 | J-18.3E | Yellow 838 | 23 | 104 | H-18.2G | Navy 087 | 12 |  |
| 103 | J-18.3E |  | 2 | 104 | H-18.3G | Orange 747 | 16 |  |
| 103 | J-18.4E | Orange 970 | 19 | 105 | H-18.4G | Black 928 | 25 |  |
| 103 | J-18.4E |  | 1 | 105 | G-18.1A | Green 504 | 17 |  |

Comment: While the likn to the spreadsheet might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contaiined. Please briefly describe the relevant parts of your spreadshet directly in the question body and include sample data. Show what you have tried including sample data, what you found from this site, from the official resources for end-users and why they didn't meet your needs. Please [edit] your question to provide the requested details. Once you have done that it can be reviewed, reopened, and answered.

Comment: If you need further help, please read first [Guides to ask a \[google-sheets\] question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/88163).

Comment: I thought I did that. I'm not sure what else I can say... I described in detail what I was looking for. What information is missing?

Comment: @Dustin add the sample data and the formula that you tried direclty into the question body. Include the data from the cell references used in your formula as well the the expected result. You don't have to all add all the rows that are included in the spreadsheet, add some representative rows. The best is that you create a small demo so the cell reference in the formula shown in the question matches the data shown in the question.

Comment: @Rubén I think I am closer to what you're looking for. I downloaded as CSV, opened in Notepad++, and copied/pasted the information. Problem is, I can't figure out how to get the carriage returns into the message, so I'm afraid it's all going to be one line.

Comment: @doubleunary thank you for the formula. I tried it and it seemed to be working, but was returning incorrect data on some lines.

Comment: Please show your _manually entered_ desired results in the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xIum-fNKfdS4XWtpaHHJpluTUA3kUEDDMzStQsSxyi4/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @doubleunary Updated! I created another tab and manually entered the desired results in 'I', and entered an explanation where 'I' should be blank. I appreciate your efforts. I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `I4`, use `query()` to get the report, and `vlookup()` with a compound key to put the results in the correct rows, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      E4:E & F4:F, 
      query( 
        { A4:D, A4:A & B4:B }, 
        "select Col5, sum(Col4) 
         where Col3 is null 
         group by Col5 
         label sum(Col4) '' ", 0 
      ), 
      2, false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To remove results where there are priors, use `countifs()` in cell `J4`, like this:

```
=map( 
  E4:E, F4:F, I4:I, 
  lambda( 
    route, zone, notIn, 
    if( 
      1 = countifs(E4:route, route, F4:zone, zone), 
      notIn, 
      iferror(1/0) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```